# How to add the image accept to a Material UI modal input field

Tags: reactjs, image, material-ui, modal-dialog

Here's the code for what I have currently
I took the basic template from it's documentation website and added some things

```
<Dialog open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
<DialogTitle>Add New Channel</DialogTitle>
<DialogContent>
<DialogContentText>Fill in Channel Details</DialogContentText>
<TextField
autoFocus
margin="normal"
id="name"
label="Channel Name"
type="text"
fullWidth
variant="standard"
/>
<TextField
autoFocus
margin="dense"
id="name"
label="Description"
type="text"
fullWidth
variant="standard"
/>
<div className="logofield">
<TextField
autoFocus
margin="dense"
id="logo"
type="file"
fullWidth
variant="standard"
/>
</div>
</DialogContent>
<DialogActions>
<FcPlus size={34} onClick={handleClose}>
Submit
</FcPlus>
</DialogActions>
</Dialog>
```

I tried "accept="image/*" " but it still remained as "All Files"

Answer (score 0):

You can add props for input element by using `inputProps` field in `TextField`
Example from mui docs,

```
const inputProps = {
  accept: "image/*",
};
return <TextField id="time" type="time" inputProps={inputProps} />
```

For more information, search for inputProps in mui docs

Answer (score 0):

After searching  the material UI official site [TextField component](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/), I found that MUI does not directly accept files in  TextField as `accept="image/*"`

Hence we have to use only HTML input element with `type="file"`

I tried with the below codes and also made some changes in your code. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/mui-image-add-to-input-4xnc3q?file=%2Fsrc%2FYourModal.js%3A61%2C44) is for your reference,

```
 <DialogContent>
        <DialogContentText>Fill in Channel Details</DialogContentText>
        <TextField
          autoFocus
          margin="normal"
          id="name"
          label="Channel Name"
          type="text"
          fullWidth
          variant="standard"
        />
        <TextField
          autoFocus
          margin="dense"
          id="description"
          label="Description"
          type="text"
          fullWidth
          variant="standard"
        />
        <div className="logofield">
          <input
            type="file"
            id="logo"
            onChange={handleFileChange}
            accept="image/*"
          />
        </div>
      </DialogContent>
```